# PDF - Can select text, but empty lines are copied

Tags: pdf, preview, copy-paste

Preview app allows me to select lines and words of text. However, when I copy and paste it into another app, empty characters are pasted.

For example, I select 3 rows of text and paste it, but 3 rows of empty text have been pasted.

On macOS Sierra with preview and the PDF files in question do not seem to be protected as I can both select text and choose `Edit->Copy`.

What is this and how I can overcome this?

For example, I wanted to copy this

[image]

and I got this

[image]

As you can see, I did not get those weird characters that people get when copy from protected document.

Comment: At worst, pdf is simply a container. Are you generating the pdf? Are they commercially prepared? [This is probably intentional by the creator of the files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61437/preview-copies-aliens-how-to-change-the-encoding-make-it-work) but more investigation or detail is needed. If you can make a short TextEdit doc and print it to pdf - you should be able to make sure your preview app and pasteboard are functioning properly.

Comment: Also check encoding with an export of one document in question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129832/5472

Comment: @bmike The PSD is a book that you receive as PDF and portions I wanted to copy/paste are related to code examples.

Comment: @bmike Check my edit please. I do not get those weird chars, but literary empty lines. Like keyboard space was typed 100 times.

Comment: @bmikeThis seems to help https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129832/9652. THANKS!